# Android - no known package when getting value for resource number

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have recently updated my android sdk, and all of a sudden when i try and build my android app, the app appears on my device, but doesnt take the app icon and the name is the package name not the app name, and then crashes straight away.

In the logcat, the image below is produced:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this, or know how to fix it?!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: I just got the same error:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488685/eclipse-juno-adt-23-0-2-resourcesnotfoundexception

Comment: Yep, tried clean and rebuild. Have tried blowing away sdk's and downloading them again. Tried downloading sdk's to new location but still no luck

Comment: I encountered the same problem - updated to all of the recent ADT tools for Eclipse and suddenly one of my projects refuses to launch. I've cleaned the project, restarted Eclipse, rebuilt the project based on the original source, cleaned again, updated the support libraries, updated Google Play Services - nothing works. Spent the whole day so far trying to figure things out.

Comment: I am also experiencing this after updating build tools.

Comment: Check out the comments on the post from @MD1984. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488685/eclipse-juno-adt-23-0-2-resourcesnotfoundexception - this bug has been fixed with 21.0.2